# draw.io codigo a diagrama

Tags: dfd

Es posible pasar de algún tipo de código a diagrama en draw.io?

Imagino algo así (sintaxis inventada para el ejemplo);

```
Start("inicio")
connectTo("action("Enviar contraseña"))
ask("¿Usuario existe?)
Etc
```

Y así poder crear un diagrama tipo flujo de datos o bmpn a partir de las instrucciones?

Comment: ¿Qué dice la documentación de dicha aplicación?

Comment: No encontré nada al respecto. Existe una app llamada https://app.code2flow.com que hace justamente lo que quiero, pero no me sirve porque necesito hacerlo para draw.io y poder exportar esos diagramas ahí, y por lo que veo no se puede